# Eloquent - Looking up data of Table 1, while having the PK of Table 3

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel/Eloquent. I have a question about accessing data from a table. The db structure is

1. Table 1 (I want to load this table)

   - No FK to any other table.
2. Table 2

   - Contains FK to Table 1
3. Table 3 (I have the PK for this table, when I need data for Table 1)

   - Contains FK to Table 2

I am not sure how should the Model for Table 1 look like, as I don't have any PK or FK for that table.

Many Thanks!

Comment: If you don't have PK for table 1 what column are you referencing for FK in table 2 and 3?

Comment: The FK in Table 3, refers to PK in Table 2 and FK in Table 2, refers to PK in Table 1. So Table 2 is like child of Table 1, and Table 3, is child of Table 2.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood when you said "I don't have any PK or FK for that table".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, Model3 belongs to Model2 which belongs to Model1. So, do something like this to get Model1 data by PK from Model3:

```
$table1Data = Model3::find($pk)->relationToModel2()->first()->relationToModel1()->first();
```

Or by using `whereHas()` method:

```
$table1Data = Model1::whereHas('relationToModel2', function ($q) use ($pk) {
    $q->whereHas('relationToModel3', function ($q) use($pk) {
        $q->where('id', $pk);
    });
})->first();
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it out. Will update with my results.

Comment: Could you please explain, what is relationToModel2? How does the implementation look like? Sorry for the dumb q, as I said, I am new to Laravel/Eloquent.

Comment: You should read [Eloquent Relationships docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships). In the first example, both relations will be `belongsTo()`. In the second example, both relations will be `hasMany()`